# im making a column in a body content that looks border with description name

Tags: html, css

I am beginner and i am doing self study how to master this programing language html and css.

I have 3 columns in my body and I want a design like a tab border while the paragraph is inside in the box border. The color on the top of the border is red with tab name.
The picture below shows what I want to acchieve

http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2gu9yzn&s=8

```
<style>
    body{
        background-color:#EDC8F7;
    }

    #column h3 {
        display:block;
        width:300px;
        background-color:#333;
        border:solid 1px #fff;  
        text-align:center;
        color:#fff;
    }       

    p {
        border:solid 1px #fff;
        width:300px;
        height:400px;
    }
</style>

<body>
    <div id = "column">
        <h3>ipsum</h3>
        <p>paragraph</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: post whatever you have tried.

Comment: <html>
<head>
<title>column</title>


<style>

body{
background-color:#EDC8F7;


}
 #column h3 {

  display:block;
  width:300px;
  background-color:#333;
  border:solid 1px #fff; 
  text-align:center;
  color:#fff;
}  

 p {
  border:solid 1px #fff;
  width:300px;
  height:400px;

  }
  





</style>
<body>

<div id = "column">
 
 <h3> ipsum</h3>

<p>paragraph</p>
</div>

</body>
</head>
</html>

Answer (score 0):

For this I would consider looking into [Bootstrap Panels](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#panels).
Here is how:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">Your panel heading here/div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    And your panel content here...
  </div>
</div>
```

You can further customize your panel. For example if you want a red background heading you could use `<div class="panel panel-danger">` instead of `<div class="panel panel-default">`

Hope that helps.